# How can I remap to Shift Command Click&Drag?

Tags: interface, 3d-view, shortcut, osx

I'm on an iMac using an Apple wireless keyboard and a Magic Mouse. I'm trying to remap buttons so that I can Move the 3D view left, right, up, and down with Shift Command Click&Drag. This is what I tried to customize in the Input tab of User Preferences:

[image]

That doesn't work, even though I managed to remap zooming with Shift Click&Drag pretty much the same way:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I haven't used a mac for a few years but I expect you may have a system action getting the event before blender and not passing it on. Using xfce4 Cmd+middle mouse = send window to the back. Similarly F12 is (was?) used on osx and needs to be cleared in system preferences for blender to use it. Either find what is using it and adjust the system settings or choose another combination.

Comment: @sambler Thanks for your reply. To my knowledge, the only mouse-related actions on Mac are "Hot Corners", which I'm not using.